# NJ Highway accident hot spots

Tags: geospatial, research, traffic

I am conducting a hazardous vulnerability assessment of truck spills on main highways in NJ. I am looking for any type of data (GIS, spreadsheets, statistical analysis) of hotspot locations of where truck accidents are most likely to occur on a highway

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the [The New Jersey Department of Transportation (NJDOT)](http://www.state.nj.us/transportation/refdata/) portal?  Most of the data seems to be in PDF format but it is there.